# How do I obtain readings using an AD8302?

Tags: labview

I need to use an AD 8302 Gain and Phase detector along with a SynthHD frequency generator to design a Vector Network Analyzer. Before I get to that I wanted to try and obtain readings on my PC. There are many projects online that seem to show readings taken from the AD 8302 sent to LabView and Matlab where the results are shown graphically, however nothing specifies how to make the connections and what coding is required.

Here is the link to the datasheet for the [AD 8302](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8302.pdf). How do I obtain readings using an AD8302?

Answer (score 1):

Those power and phase detectors are still analog outputs - they output a voltage to represent the power level on the input. You still need to use some for of digitizer, be it in a prebuilt piece of equipment such as a multimeter or such, or a ADC board you design yourself. You can't just plug the powerdetector into your computer and expect results to come out.

The datasheet shows that you should expect aproximatly 30 mV/dB slope.

The advantage of using prebuilt hardware is that the drivers for matlab and labview potentially already exist. You could also look at ADC devboards, which sometimes come with software to interface to matlab and so on.